# MongoDB throwing TimeoutException on collection find?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, nosql

I'm getting an unknown and unexpected error when trying to get a players data with MongoDB? I'm a newbie to mongo so I was wondering if anyone could help.

```
System.TimeoutException: 'A timeout occured after 3000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "127.0.0.1:3306" }", EndPoint: "127.0.0.1:3306", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid BinaryConnection state transition from 4 to Failed.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenConnectionHelper.FailedOpeningConnection(Exception wrappedException)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.<HeartbeatAsync>d__27.MoveNext()" }] }.'
```

C#:

```
if (HasAuthenticated)
{
    return;
}

var database = Program.Server.DatabaseHandler.MongoDatabase;
var collection = database.GetCollection<User>("habbo_users");

var playerData = collection.Find(x => x.AuthTicket == authTicket).Limit(1).First();

if (playerData == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Couldn't find players data using this auth ticket.");
}

Console.WriteLine(playerData.Username + " logged in with " + playerData.AuthTicket + " and ID: " + playerData.Id);
```

If throws it on this line

```
var playerData = collection.Find(x => x.AuthTicket == authTicket).Limit(1).First();
```

Comment: Does this happen for both valid and invalid users, or only in one of the two cases?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it happens on both, I've only got 1 user and it does exist, so it should be valid.

Comment: Just double checked, it happens on both.

Comment: Check your connection string. Are you sure your connection is correct? Are you able to query any other collections in this database?

Answer (score 0):

Actual source of exception is described by this part:

> HeartbeatException: "System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid
>   BinaryConnection state transition from 4 to Failed. ...

This is bug of `MongoDB.Driver.Core` of version `2.7.0` and lower, but it only hides some other exception. Check your `MongoDB.Driver.Core` version. If it is lower than `2.7.1` then update it till this version or higher. It would not fix your problem, but you'll get the actual exception hidden behind.

The actual exception will be at same place: `... HeartbeatException: [exception text here]`.

If you need more information on this you can visit [issue itself](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2005).